# Responisve ul list . How do I approach this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

here is the fiddle I am working on [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/yMrpf/2/)

How do I make this column completely responsive so that when the screen size becomes less I want all the elements to stay inline rather than stacking below one another.

How to solve this ?

Here is the sample markup

```
<div id="apologies-list">
                <ul id="apologies-list-content">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">
                        <div class="user-avatar list-padding span12 clearfix" > 
                          <div class="span1">
                            <input class="case" name="case" type="checkbox" value="">
                          </div>
                          <div class="span2">
                            <img id="list-avatar" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="span6">
                            <span>Apologies initials</span>
                            <small>January 31, 2009 9:18 am</small>
                          </div>
                          <div class="span3 ">
                            <span class="badge badge-info custom-badge">2</span>
                            <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

For CSS please check my fiddle.

Comment: Why are you still using BS2?

Answer (score 0):

use css media queries

```
    @media screen and (max-width:400px)
    {
    #apologies-list-content li div {display:inline-block}
    }
```